# C# System.Text.Json Deserialize JSON-string with Cyrillic symbols - how can i prevent conversion to escape-string?

Tags: c#, serialization, system.text.json

I'm trying to deserialize Json-string with cyrillic-symbols, and i get JsonObject with string-properties as escape string:

Source JsonString:
`{"ERROR":"-","ERRORS":{"bdate":["Поле \"Дата рождения\" должно содержать корректную дату в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ"]},"STATUS":400}`

JsonObject after deserialization:
`{"ERROR":"-","ERRORS":{"bdate":["\u041F\u043E\u043B\u0435 \u0022\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u0440\u043E\u0436\u0434\u0435\u043D\u0438\u044F\u0022 ... \u0414\u0414.\u041C\u041C.\u0413\u0413\u0413\u0413"]},"STATUS":400}`

My code:

```
        using HttpClient httpClient = new();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url);
        // response:
        // {"ERROR":"-","ERRORS":{"bdate":["Поле \"Дата рождения\" должно содержать корректную дату в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ"]},"STATUS":400}

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin, UnicodeRanges.Cyrillic),
        };

        // First Attempt
        string responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // responseStr value:
        // {"ERROR":"-","ERRORS":{"bdate":["Поле \"Дата рождения\" должно содержать корректную дату в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ"]},"STATUS":400}
        JsonObject? jsonResult1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(responseStr);
        // jsonResult1:
        //{"ERROR":"-","ERRORS":{"bdate":["\u041F\u043E\u043B\u0435 \u0022\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u0440\u043E\u0436\u0434\u0435\u043D\u0438\u044F\u0022 ... \u0434\u0430\u0442\u0443 \u0432 \u0444\u043E\u0440\u043C\u0430\u0442\u0435 \u0414\u0414.\u041C\u041C.\u0413\u0413\u0413\u0413"]},"STATUS":400}

        // Second Attempt
        JsonObject? jsonResult2 = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<JsonObject>(options);
        // jsonResult2:
        //{"ERROR":"-","ERRORS":{"bdate":["\u041F\u043E\u043B\u0435 \u0022\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u0440\u043E\u0436\u0434\u0435\u043D\u0438\u044F\u0022 ... \u0434\u0430\u0442\u0443 \u0432 \u0444\u043E\u0440\u043C\u0430\u0442\u0435 \u0414\u0414.\u041C\u041C.\u0413\u0413\u0413\u0413"]},"STATUS":400}
```

How can i prevent this deserialize-behavior?

Comment: `ReadFromJsonAsync` is designed to be used to *read* a JSON document into a custom object model, not to put it back into a `JsonObject`, which has no understanding of your serialization settings. If you want to reserialize your custom object, pass those serializer settings to the serializer, not the deserializer. Putting it another way: the `JsonObject` that you have doesn't have any string representation until you ask it for one, how are you doing that?

Comment: I don't need to serialize the object again, I need to deserialize it and get some of its properties

Comment: If I deserialize to JsonElement (instead JsonObject - JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>), then everything is fine, no string conversion occurs!

Comment: Well then just deserialize it to JsonElement then. Any case the docs say "The System.Json namespace was designed for Silverlight, which is no longer supported. For processing JSON, we recommend using APIs in the System.Text.Json namespace instead." so you shouldn't use `JsonObject`. Or use a proper object model, like you're supposed to. `JsonElement` and friends are designed for dynamic JSON where you don't know the model.

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t think that JsonObject is not from System.Text.Json...

Comment: Side note: you are missing a `using` on the `response` object.

Answer (score 0):

i decided to work with **JsonDocument**

```
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(personDictionary));
        string responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(responseStr);
        string result = "";
        foreach (var elem in jsonDoc.RootElement.EnumerateObject()) {
            result += $"{elem.Name}: {elem.Value}\n";
        }

        // result:
        //
        // ERROR: -
        // ERRORS: { "bdate":["Поле \"Дата рождения\" должно содержать корректную дату в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ"],"docdt":["Поле \"Дата выдачи документа\" должно содержать корректную дату в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ"]}
        // STATUS: 400
```

All is OK!